# sql how to sort by a union's subquery without adding a column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I mostly have the query I need, but I noticed that I still get duplicates from the first select and the second select. I thought that using UNION instead of UNION ALL would remove duplicates, but because they have a different sequence number they are not removed.  How can I order my results by the select statement without adding an unnecessary seq column?

```
select 1 as seq, t.* from template t 
WHERE status = 'ACTIVE' and t.title ~* '.*동\s*아\s*리\s*로\s*고\s*.*' 
UNION 
select 2 as seq, t.* from template t 
WHERE status = 'ACTIVE' and t.title ~* any(array['.*동\s*아\s*리\s*로\s*고\s*.*']) 
UNION select 3 as seq, t.* from template t WHERE status = 'ACTIVE' 
order by seq asc
```

Comment: There are no duplicates, because the first column is 1 in one table and 2 in the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `order by`:

```
select t.*
from template t 
where status = 'ACTIVE' 
order by (t.title ~* '.*동\s*아\s*리\s*로\s*고\s*.*') desc,
         (t.title ~* any(array['.*동\s*아\s*리\s*로\s*고\s*.*']) desc;
```

Comment: this kind of order by an expression seems to work in a single table but not on the union's order by.

do I need to give a name to the union somehow to be able to reference it instead of template t?

Comment: figured it out just need to name the subquery. sorry I'm still such a noob. there is too much to learn in this world